# Keyboard information inside "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation"

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-softkeyboard

How can I deduce the information if the keyboard is visible while device orientation is changed? Does this information is sent inside - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)iFromInterfaceOrientation method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you will have to subscribe to some notification and keep the info somewhere.

Have a look at

```
UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
```